# Open source Spreadsheet Solution

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Looking for an open source web Spreadsheet framework written in java / JavaScript so I can wrap in java library and use it in as a  GWT module and use it my GWT application

Any Ideas

Answer (score 4):

There are some:

http://www.simple-groupware.de/cms/Spreadsheet/Home

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sheetster/

http://code.google.com/p/zkspreadsheet/

and a full list for digging:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_spreadsheets

They are javascript so they should be possible to wrap in JSNI to be accessed from GWT.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Spreadsheet](http://www.simple-groupware.de/cms/Spreadsheet/Home) may be something to look at or [Sheetster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sheetster) is another one.

Comment: Oops, also forgot to mention http://code.google.com/p/zkspreadsheet/ as another interesting one.